# Redis log producing same message

Tags: redis, predis, nosql

I have a redis cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves. All the instances are running fine except for one master and its slave. For some reason, this master/slave instance keep closing server connections. When i checked the error logs on both the master and slave, they keep producing this message over and over and nothing else:

```
CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
...
```

Any insight on what is happening with this master and it's slave?

Comment: What version of Redis are you running? I guess the CONFIG REWRITE command must have been issued by someone, not likely that it goes off automatically. Maybe there is a bug in the implementation, causing it to run in circles. From the documentation page, it looks like a rather complex thing. Have you tried restarting the master and slave?

Comment: Could it be that somehow the master and slave are both 'slaveof' the other server now? So the 'master' has become a slave of the slave? And the slave is now not just a slave of the master but also also a slave of the slave of the slave? etc.

Comment: I got it working now. For some reason, it was the sentinel instances that were causing this issue. At one point, i tempered with the .rdb (basically deleted it and changed its location) and after that, this started happening. Plus one node for some reason had two sentinel processes running at the same time, and one could not just die until i finally killed its process using the kill -9 command.

Comment: Ok good for you. Thanks for the update. Redis Sentinel is new to me, learning about it now... :-)

Comment: So you're running Redis Cluster AND Sentinel? If you're using Redis Cluster, do NOT use Sentinel as well. Redis Cluster does it's own failover management and running Sentinel on it additionally will cause issues.